# How can I view my partition sizes and mount points?

Tags: partitioning

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. The installation was done by a computer shop (I had a faulty hard drive, which they replaced). I'd like to see if they set up my partitions as I requested. How can I view the partition sizes and mount points?

Comment: You can use the application called "Disks" which is most probably installed by default.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GParted](https://gparted.org/)(GNOME Partition Editor). To install it in Ubuntu, run the following commands(one-by-one) :-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

After installation, you can use GParted Partition Manger to view partition sizes and mount points.

Answer (score 4):

try `df`. Sometimes is enough. By default you get something like

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       65389132  23268884  38775608  38% /
tmpfs            2004540     19004   1985536   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5      169672296 142616624  18430080  89% /home
/dev/sda1       64147300  50588732  10293340  84% /backups
```

several options available.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command lines, that together will give you a good overview of the partitions (location, sizes, free space and mount points),

```
df -h
sudo parted -ls
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

If your terminal window is wide enough (for example 130 characters), you can combine the `lsblk` commands to

```
sudo lsblk -fm
```