# Unable to Mount 15 GB Volume (Ubuntu Studio) (USB)

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I had the installation files for Ubuntu Studio 17.04 on my USB drive and had to format it. So I installed Gparted to format my usb drive and it worked. But the problem is now i am unable to Mount my usb drive within Ubuntu. I keep getting this error message whenever i try to open the drive

**Rejected send message, 4 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.48" (uid=1000 pid=1276 comm="/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor ") interface="org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem" member="Mount" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.7" (uid=0 pid=632 comm="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd ")**

Comment: usisks2 file-system is actually full of bugs, maybe have a look at the list and add to it if necessary. Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2

Comment: Have you tried creating a FAT32 file system on it instead of udisk2?

Comment: Yeah, no matter what file system i use, the usb won't mount or even show up on my desktop, but the drive is recognized in the 'lsusb' command and in Gparted. I have no clue what to do

Comment: Maybe the following link will help you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072; If still problems, analyze the problem according to the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: None of these are working, no matter what i do, the usb will not mount

Comment: When the USB drive is connected, please run the commands specified in the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/967599/how-can-i-view-my-partition-sizes-and-mount-points/967622#967622 ; and edit your question to show the output (of the commands). Add four spaces to the beginning of each line to render the output as 'code'. -- The commands are: `df -h` ; `sudo parted -ls` ; `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m`